# json object change value function based on passed in key

Tags: javascript, json, object, key

I am wanting to change the value inside a json object using a function that allows you to pass in what key you want to change (pName)

```
var users = {
  john: {
    read: true,
    write: false
  },
  mike: {
    read: true,
    write: false
  }
}

var chgPermission = function (userName, pName, pValue) {
  if (users[userName]) {
    users[userName].pName = pValue;
  } else {
    console.log(`Could not find: ${userName}`)
  }
}

chgPermission("mike", "write", true)
```

This does not work because it looks for users[username].pName (which does not exist) instead of users[userName].write

what do i need to do to have the function allow me to change the value of the key that is passed in.

thank you

Comment: [There is no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Answer (score 2):

I think you want something like this:

```
var chgPermission = function (userName, pName, pValue) {
  if (users[userName]) {
    users[userName][pName]= pValue;
  } else {
    console.log(`Could not find: ${userName}`)
  }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for, Thanks!!

Comment: Perfect, Can you mark this answer as accepted, please?

Answer (score 1):

Just change `users[userName].pName` to `users[userName][pName]`.